# Why does the OnInit lifecyclehook not work?

Tags: angular, typescript, web

Why doesn't this work??
The console keeps giving me a type error; It can't read property sort. Can anyone help me? 
'''

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from 'src/app/models/order';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() orders: Order[];

  sortedOrders: Order[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sortedOrders = this.sortOrders(this.orders);
    console.log(this.sortedOrders);
  }

  sortOrders(orders: Order[]): Order[] {
    return orders.sort((a, b) => a.personName.localeCompare(b.personName));
  }

}
```

Comment: Where's `sort`? What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Hi! In the `sortOrders` method, can you do a  `console.log(orders);` and write the result? Perhaps it's because `orders` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook as it is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view

Try like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.sortedOrders = this.sortOrders(this.orders);
    console.log(this.sortedOrders);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `@Input()`, so `OnInit` your data will not be available, so you should be doing it in `OnChanges`

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.sortedOrders = this.sortOrders(this.orders);
    console.log(this.sortedOrders);
  }
```